# Stop Dreamweaver from formatting my code

Tags: dreamweaver

I'm currently using CS6 but I'm pretty sure DW has been doing this for even the oldest versions I've used. Basically I type this:

```
<td>
    &nbsp;
</td>
```

And Dreamweaver turns it into this:

```
<td>&nbsp;

</td>
```

Worse yet is if the first style comes out of SVN, and I change any little thing, DW makes that change all over the file. This adds pain when Diffing the file to have all these edits that have nothing to do with what actually got changed.

So how do I get Dreamweaver to not re-write code? Specifically to not rewrite code to a format no one wants?

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the way Dreamweaver formats your tags by going into the preferences->code format->tag libraries->HTML->td format entry and changing its settings to:

Line Breaks:  No Line Breaks

Contents: Not Formatted

That should fix it from altering your td tag when you apply source formatting.

Comment: The problem is not really how Dreamweaver formats the tags as I'm writing the code. It's that it re-writes the code, only in the specific instance of using a non-breaking space inside the <td> tag.